# When is it most effective to take a Tryptophan supplement?

Tags: supplement

Tryptophan is an amino acid and a building block for certain hormones such as melatonin and serotonin. If you're looking to improve your mood I would imagine taking a Tryptophan supplement may be most effective in the morning to enhance serotonin production whereas if you're trying to address issues with sleep you may opt to take a Tryptophan supplement in the early evening to enhance melatonin production. When is it most effective to take a Tryptophan supplement for subjective to mood or sleep related issues?